# Find SQLPLUS under SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)

Tags: linux, oracle11g, sqlplus, suse

We have an Oracle 11.g running on the SUSE Ent. Server.
It is really unbelievable from me, but I cannot find the SQLPlus application on the server.
What should be the most typical location of that application? What is the most typical location of the Oracle Database instance?
I thought it is /opt/oracle, but this folder seems no to be the right one, because it does not contains the files I would expect. 
Is it possible, that SQLPlus application has been "removed" after the installation?

Comment: Did you try this command `which sqlplus` in order to find where it `lives`

Comment: Does `source oraenv` work without giving any error messages?

Comment: which: no sqlplus in (/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/opt/jrockit/current/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin:/opt/jrockit/current/bin)

Does it mean, that there is no sqlplus installed?

Comment: printenv | grep -i oracle
ORA_CRS_HOME=/opt/oracle/install/product/11gR1/crs
ORA_ASM_HOME=/opt/oracle/install/product/11gR1/asm
ORACLE_SID=persreg
ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle/install
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/install/product/11gR1/db/bin

If I navigate to ORACLE_HOME folder, I can find the sqlplus program.
But: if I type sqlplus, I got the following output:

If 'sqlplus' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found sqlplus
-bash: sqlplus: command not found

What is the problem?